# How to remove item from the following data type in Python?

Tags: python

If I have the following data type:

```
[('a', 'digital-text'), ('b', 'bbbbbbb'), ('c', '1318913293'), ('d', '1-3')]
```

How to I remove item `b` so the output will look like:

```
[('a', 'digital-text'), ('c', '1318913293'), ('d', '1-3')]
```

How do I also check if `b` exists before deleting it? I tried `if 'b' in xxxx` but this can't find it

I am new to Python

Comment: Do you already know where "item `b`" is?

Comment: no, you don't know the location

Answer (score 7):

You could use a list comprehension like this:

```python
something = [(key, value) for key, value in something if key != 'b']
```

However, it looks like you're trying to reinvent a dictionary for some reason. If it doesn't have to be ordered, just use a dictionary:

```python
something = {
    'a': 'digital-text',
    'b': 'bbbbbbb',
    'c': '1318913293',
    'd': '1-3',
}
del something['b']
```

If it does need to be ordered, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` rather than `dict`:

```python
from collections import OrderedDict
something = OrderedDict([
    ('a', 'digital-text'),
    ('b', 'bbbbbbb'),
    ('c', '1318913293'),
    ('d', '1-3')
])
del something['b']
```

With a dictionary, if you need it back in the format you have in your question, just call `items()` on the dictionary.

```python
>>> # assuming something is an OrderedDict and you've already deleted the item
>>> # if it was a plain dict, it might be in a different order
>>> # if you haven't deleted the item, it would still be there
>>> something.items()
[('a', 'digital-text'), ('c', '1318913293'), ('d', '1-3')]
```

Additionally, to convert a list like in your question *into* some kind of dictionary, just pass it into it:

```python
>>> dict([
...     ('a', 'digital-text'),
...     ('b', 'bbbbbbb'),
...     ('c', '1318913293'),
...     ('d', '1-3')
... ])
{'a': 'digital-text', 'b': 'bbbbbbb', 'c': '1318913293', 'd': '1-3'}
```

Comment: If only one item is to be deleted, you can also avoid looking at items after the one you delete in the list by using a normal loop: `for for index, (key, value) in enumerate(the_list):
    if key == 'b':
        del the_list[index];
        break`

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension does this nicely:

```
new_list = [element for element in old_list if element[0] != "b"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For removal you can do:

```
my_list = [('a', 'digital-text'), ('b', 'bbbbbbb'), ('c', '1318913293'), ('d', '1-3')]
my_list.remove(('b', 'bbbbbbb'))
```

or:

```
my_list = [('a', 'digital-text'), ('b', 'bbbbbbb'), ('c', '1318913293'), ('d', '1-3')]
del my_list[2]
```

If you wanna create a new list without that value you can use list comprehension:

```
my_list = [('a', 'digital-text'), ('b', 'bbbbbbb'), ('c', '1318913293'), ('d', '1-3')]
new_list = [(key, value) for key, value in my_list if key != 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "filter":

```
newList = filter(lambda (k, v): k != 'b', oldList)
```

In python 2 it will return filtered list, in python 3.x - iterator.